# Вопрос о создании Интерфейса для программ

Tags: html, c++, gui

Где-то краем уха услышал, что можно создать интерфейс для программы С++ на HTML (css+js). Это правда? Если, да, то можете кинуть пару обучающих книг(видео)?

Comment: Надо подключить движок браузера и использовать его, к примеру WebKit или IE плагин. Все остальное - это использование возможностей браузера плагина, который будет рендерить страницы HTML.

Comment: есть wt++ это инструментарий для разработки программ на C++ с веб-мордочками. https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Comment: Есть много инструментов, похожих на HTML. Например: htmlayout http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/ ; QML (как часть Qt), и др. Конкретные книги можно будет советовать, только после того как определитесь с инструментом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хочу вначале уточнить, что задача распадается на две части. Первая - это непосредственно Ваша программа на C++, которая будет что-то делать и взаимодействовать с пользователем через HTML интерфейс. Для решения этой части есть билиотеки, например WT (см. ниже).

Вторая часть - это это рендеринг кода HTML в красивые кнопочки, закладочки, картинки, "галочки" и другие элементы интерфейса. Это очень серьезная и объемная задача. Ей занимается целая индустрия создания браузеров. В Вашем случае подойдет либо стандартный браузер в системе пользователя, который будет направлен на локальный адрес. Либо модуль готового движка типа Gecko, или [Web-kit](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit). В любом случае выбор за вами.

## Библиотека WT. Ключевые возможности:

- Поддержка основных браузеров (Firefox/Gecko, Internet Explorer, Safari, Chrome, Konqueror и Opera), а также браузеров простого HTML (Links, Lynx).
- Разработка и развёртывание на Unix/GNU Linux или Microsoft Windows (Visual Studio).
- Идентичное поведение как при поддержке JavaScript или Ajax, так и без таковой, насколько это возможно, посредством постепенной деградации (graceful degradation) или прогрессивного расширения (progressive enhancement).
- Интегрированная поддержка Юникода и локализации.
- Эффективный рендеринг и низкая латентность.
- Поддержка перемещения с помощью истории браузера (кнопки "назад"/"вперёд" и закладки), лаконичные URL при доступности истории HTML5, оптимизация для поисковиков и однообразное поведение сессий простого HTML или Ajax.
- Настраиваемые опции отслеживания сессий, либо посредством перезаписи URL, либо с помощью использования кук.
- и еще много всего "вкусного"...

Подробности [на сайте (на русском)](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/ru/documentation)